# Чем отличаются эти IP-адреса?

Tags: ip

Вот мой IP-адрес:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть еще какой-то IP-шник, через который можно, например, запустить react-проект. Или например, программа с прокси тоже его пишет. Что это за IP-шники и чем они различаются? Я так понимаю, что IP-адрес, который выдает 2ip.ru - это мой настоящий IP-адрес и именно о нем чаще всего идет речь. А вот это что такое?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 192.168.xxx.yyy - это адрес сетевого интерфейса твоего компьютера. 82.162.xx.yyy - это адрес сетевого интерфейса компьютера провайдера, который выводит тебя в Интернет (или твоего шлюза, если у теб "белый" IP).